# finding one Special realization in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to find realization for a system like below
[image]

how can I do that in matlab.

Comment: What do you mean by "realization"? Do you mean a solution?

Comment: Writing the state space from the transfer function is called realization. I want to find a realization like this.